# gcov filter result and files

Tags: linux, eclipse, code-coverage, gcov

i'm using eclipse indigo with linux tools. one of the tools is plugin of gcov.
i have a project which is statis lib (dot a file) and another project that is a unit test that link with this lib and invoke its methods.
in both projects i added the compilation flags -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage and in the excutable project i added also a link with gcov lib (-lgcov).

the results was fine, but i got a lot of functions that seems to be of the system and not mine. like boost, basic_cstring and other not-mine code.

i want to ask how can i filter everything that is not mine. i'm interested only in the code that i wrote and not that the strcpy runs on all paths.
can i do it?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

While this question is over 4 years old, it was higher up in google results for me than what actually solved my similar problem. 
Via https://stackoverflow.com/a/14835775/2290151:

`lcov  --directory src -c -o report.info --no-external`