# gcov/lcov - How to exclude all but one directory from coverage data

Tags: bash, shell, glob, gcov, lcov

I am creating code coverage reports for my C++ projects using gcov/lcov, and I am trying to remove all files except the ones in a certain directory from the coverage report (i.e. I do not want different dependencies in various folders to show up in the report).

However I want to do this automatically and not manually. I tried the following:

`lcov -r coverage.total '!(<path>)' -o coverage.info`

But then `lcov` comes back with `Deleted 0 files`. I also tried `!(<path>)`, `'[^path]*'` and slight variations of these but nothing seems to work. I can manually remove the undesired folders for example the following does work:
`lcov -r coverage.total '/usr/libs/*' '/usr/mylibs/*' -o coverage.info`

**So my question is, how can I have `lcov` exclude all but a specific directory?**

P.S.

- I am open to workarounds (for example if this can be done with a bash script)
- I am using bash+CMake+gcov+lcov

P.S.

This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837639/is-there-a-way-to-focus-lcov-code-coverage-reports-to-just-one-or-two-directorie]()). I am asking about an **automated** way to only include files in a specific directory in the report. (for example the current directory) I am aware of the `--remove` argument but that is not an automated solution.

**Your help is greately appreciated!**

Comment: Why the down-vote?

Comment: I didn't DV, but it seems the c++ tag without specific c++ code wasn't well appreciated. Also there seems to be an easy to fing duplicate [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837639/is-there-a-way-to-focus-lcov-code-coverage-reports-to-just-one-or-two-directorie]()

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It is not a duplicate. As I mentioned in my question I want to do this automatically. Using the --remove flag would require me to do this manually for all unwanted folders for each report. I want to only include a specific folder (for example the project folder or the current directory).