portable way to exclude lcov directories
I am running lcov and I cannot prevent it from analyzing base c++ directories. I tried --no-external and it excluded everything. I tried --remove
lcov --remove <in-file> <pattern> -output-file <out-file>

It required a pattern that is very specific to the current toolchain and very detailed. There seems to be no way to have a command that will exclude everything under "/usr/include".
Here are the directories from my current output when I compile on Ubuntu 24.04, the names are different if I compile on 22.04.
include/xxx
src
/usr/include/c++/13
/usr/include/c++/13/bits
/usr/include/c++/13/ext
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/13/bits

The structure of my code is
project/include/xxx/xxx.h
project/src/xxx.cc
project/build  -- cmake build directory 

It is such a trivial request, I could not believe it has no simple solution.

lcov supports --no-external option, which can be combined with --directory and --base-directory ones to not count files outside of the specified directories: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14835775/3440745. Have you tried that approach?

This comment solved my problem, --base-directory + --no-externals

If you are using a moderately recent lcov version, then there is pretty extensive support for --exclude and --include patterns.
Seems like exactly what you are asking for.
(Inclusion/exclusion patterns can be use in any of the tools: lcov, genhtml, etc.
That can be useful in that you can collect and store all of the data - but chose to generate an HTML report for only part of it.)
